# R - Select days that are before or at least n days after event

Tags: r, time-series, subset, lubridate

I have a year of observations. Whenever an event occurs, it is marked with an "Ob" in the 2nd column.

I want to select control days, which are either before or at least 7 days after an event. The control days should be as close as possible to the event days, without being within the 7 lag days. The number of control days should match the number of event days. They should be marked in the 2nd column of the dataframe with an "Co".

```
structure(list(All = structure(c(17167, 17168, 17169, 17170, 
17171, 17172, 17173, 17174, 17175, 17176, 17177, 17178, 17179, 
17180, 17181, 17182, 17183, 17184, 17185, 17186, 17187, 17188, 
17189, 17190, 17191, 17192, 17193, 17194, 17195, 17196, 17197, 
17198, 17199, 17200, 17201, 17202, 17203, 17204, 17205, 17206, 
17207, 17208, 17209, 17210, 17211, 17212, 17213, 17214, 17215, 
17216, 17217, 17218, 17219, 17220, 17221, 17222, 17223, 17224, 
17225, 17226, 17227, 17228, 17229, 17230, 17231, 17232, 17233, 
17234, 17235, 17236, 17237, 17238, 17239, 17240, 17241, 17242, 
17243, 17244, 17245, 17246, 17247, 17248, 17249, 17250, 17251, 
17252, 17253, 17254, 17255, 17256, 17257, 17258, 17259, 17260, 
17261, 17262, 17263, 17264, 17265, 17266, 17267, 17268, 17269, 
17270, 17271, 17272, 17273, 17274, 17275, 17276, 17277, 17278, 
17279, 17280, 17281, 17282, 17283, 17284, 17285, 17286, 17287, 
17288, 17289, 17290, 17291, 17292, 17293, 17294, 17295, 17296, 
17297, 17298, 17299, 17300, 17301, 17302, 17303, 17304, 17305, 
17306, 17307, 17308, 17309, 17310, 17311, 17312, 17313, 17314, 
17315, 17316, 17317, 17318, 17319, 17320, 17321, 17322, 17323, 
17324, 17325, 17326, 17327, 17328, 17329, 17330, 17331, 17332, 
17333, 17334, 17335, 17336, 17337, 17338, 17339, 17340, 17341, 
17342, 17343, 17344, 17345, 17346, 17347, 17348, 17349, 17350, 
17351, 17352, 17353, 17354, 17355, 17356, 17357, 17358, 17359, 
17360, 17361, 17362, 17363, 17364, 17365, 17366, 17367, 17368, 
17369, 17370, 17371, 17372, 17373, 17374, 17375, 17376, 17377, 
17378, 17379, 17380, 17381, 17382, 17383, 17384, 17385, 17386, 
17387, 17388, 17389, 17390, 17391, 17392, 17393, 17394, 17395, 
17396, 17397, 17398, 17399, 17400, 17401, 17402, 17403, 17404, 
17405, 17406, 17407, 17408, 17409, 17410, 17411, 17412, 17413, 
17414, 17415, 17416, 17417, 17418, 17419, 17420, 17421, 17422, 
17423, 17424, 17425, 17426, 17427, 17428, 17429, 17430, 17431, 
17432, 17433, 17434, 17435, 17436, 17437, 17438, 17439, 17440, 
17441, 17442, 17443, 17444, 17445, 17446, 17447, 17448, 17449, 
17450, 17451, 17452, 17453, 17454, 17455, 17456, 17457, 17458, 
17459, 17460, 17461, 17462, 17463, 17464, 17465, 17466, 17467, 
17468, 17469, 17470, 17471, 17472, 17473, 17474, 17475, 17476, 
17477, 17478, 17479, 17480, 17481, 17482, 17483, 17484, 17485, 
17486, 17487, 17488, 17489, 17490, 17491, 17492, 17493, 17494, 
17495, 17496, 17497, 17498, 17499, 17500, 17501, 17502, 17503, 
17504, 17505, 17506, 17507, 17508, 17509, 17510, 17511, 17512, 
17513, 17514, 17515, 17516, 17517, 17518, 17519, 17520, 17521, 
17522, 17523, 17524, 17525, 17526, 17527, 17528, 17529, 17530, 
17531), class = "Date"), Event = c("Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", 
"Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", NA, "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", 
"Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", 
"Ob", "Ob", "Ob", NA, NA, "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", NA, NA, "Ob", 
"Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", NA, "Ob", "Ob", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", NA, NA, "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", 
NA, NA, NA, "Ob", NA, "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Ob", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Ob", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Ob", NA, NA, "Ob", "Ob", NA, NA, "Ob", "Ob", 
"Ob", "Ob", "Ob", NA, "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", NA, "Ob", 
"Ob", NA, "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", "Ob", NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
365L))
```

EDIT:
I had an idea now:

```
idx <- which(!is.na(df$Event))

idx_list = list()

for (a in 1:7) {
  idx_list[[a]] = idx + a}

idx = unique(unlist(idx_list))
```

This will select all "blocked" days, so I would only need a routine now to select the n closest days to the blocked days. n should be the same number as the observation days.

Comment: I'm not sure how clear your description is. The very first row has an observation on the 1st January. There are a further 10 consecutive observations after that. If you want a control day for the 1st January, is it allowed to be on an existing observation day, like the 8th of January, or should it be on the first NA day?  Also, there are 5 observations in the last 7 days. Can you explain how the number of control days can be the same as the number of observation days if there needs to be a lag of 7 days for the controls? Would we need to lengthen  the data frame to fit these in?

Comment: Thanks for your respond. A control day can ONLY be a Na day. It doesnt matter if it is before the event (in case of december) or after the event (at least 7 days after). In my example no day in January or february can be a control day, since there is no 7 day gap after an event. In december its the same, but the days in november (6-12) can be used since the last event day was 31th of october. 12th of november is before the event, so that is fine.

Comment: So March 23 should be the control date for every observation up to that point?

Comment: Please have a look that my edit above.

Comment: Ok - in your question you say 7 days *after* but in the comment you said before or after. Can you update the question if you are OK with *before*?

Comment: March 23th is the first day of the n days I need. In the end I need the same number of control days as I have observation days.

Comment: I just updated the question. Its a bit tricky to explain. The control day can be before an event, but it has to be at least 7 days after the last event.

Comment: Ok that's helpful. Basically we need a set of clear rules to write the code.

Comment: Actually the idx code I figured out it already one half of the question. Its actually a very easy rule. Now I just need to find a way to select the n days, that are closest to an observation without being in the blocked days.

Answer (score 0):

Steps of my answer:

1. Created a column with the difference between each date
2. Selected the events that were isolated from others (from atleast 7 days)
3. Looped trought the resulting indexes with `purrr::map`
4. Used `accumulate` on the date differences starting from the index, to check when was the nearest 7-day-apart date
5. Created the new column with "Co" on those dates

```
library(tidyverse)

#Create a column with the space (in days) between the dates in each row
df = df %>% mutate(All.diff = c(NA, diff(All)))

indexes = which(df$Event == "Ob") %>% #at the rows where we have an event
  .[which(diff(.) >= 7)] %>% #check if there is at least 7 days before the last event
  map_dbl(function(index){ #for each index
    nskip = df$All.diff[index:nrow(df)] %>% #get the differences in dates until that index
      accumulate(sum) %>% #sum the date differences
      {which(. >= 7)[1]} #get the first index where the sum of the differences exeed 7
    return(index + nskip) #return the original index minus the number of days to skip
  })

df$Control = NA
df$Control[indexes] = "Co"

> df$All[indexes]
[1] "2017-03-23" "2017-04-04" "2017-04-19" "2017-05-01" "2017-11-07"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. The end result is not what I am looking for. The first control day should be 23th of March. With your solution its 18th of March, which is not at least 7 days away from the last event. The other days like 24, 25th of March are not included. And when I have 101 events, I also need 101 control days.

Comment: But it is 7 days before the next event, iguess i don't understand what you meant by "either before or at least 7 days after an event". If it is one or the other, you want both 23th and the 18th. If it is one and the other, you want some date in the middle, 7 days away from both the last and the next event. Which is it?

Comment: Oh ok, I see. I meant before (can be also the day before an event) or 7 days after an event. So days like 23-25th of March are ok, since they are 7 days after an event. Also all days in october (apart from 31th) can be control days. And out of all these possible control days, I want the one that are closest to the event days.

Comment: Ok, the logic of the answer is still the same, i only changed the "direction" it was looking for the dates. Check my edit!